# Length of shortest word that contains all triples

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Given a finite set $M := \{1...n\}$, what is the shortest word $w \in M^*$ so that the set of all subwords of $w$ is a superset of $M^3$? A subword is a prefix of a suffix.

For $1 \leq n \leq 2$ it is $n^3+2$ and I assume this holds for every $n$.

Comment: With that amount of data - id est, $n=1$ or $n=2$ and $g(n)>0$ for $n>0$ - it could very well be $n^3+2+n(n-1)(n-2)=2n^3-3n^2+2n+2$.

Comment: See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) for some inspiration.

Comment: Well, $n^3 + 2$ is also the lower bound, so I hoped it might also be the upper.

Comment: @Arthur that's the solution! The De Brujin graph is Hamiltonian, which proves my claim. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Arthur, the De Brujin graph of all words in $M^3$ is hamiltonian.
Pick a node (i.e. a word of length 3) and walk an Hamilton path of length $n^3-1$. Since every edge adds a single character to the previous word, this yields a word of length $3 + n^3 - 1$ that contains every word of length 3.